# Quick g++ Error diagnosis for a noob

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

can someone tell how to fix the compile errors g++ gives me for this short program or anything else thats terrible in it. I'm a noob. Thanks. I know most of them are because I don't know what I'm doing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    struct RGB {
        float r;
        float g;
        float b;
    };

    int w = atoi(argv[1]);
    int h = atoi(argv[2]);

    vector<vector RGB > image;
    image.resize(w);
    for (int q = 0; q < w; ++q)
    image[q].resize(h);

    for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j){
            float col = float (((i & 0x08) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x08) == 0));
            image[i][j].r = col;
            image[i][j].g = col;
            image[i][j].b = col;
        }
    }

    string filename = string(argv[3]) + ".ppm";
    ofstream file(filename);
    file << "P3" << endl;
    file << w << " " << h << endl;
    file << "255" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j){
            float col = float (((i & 0x08) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x08) == 0));
            file << image[i][j].r*255 << " ";
            file << image[i][j].g*255 << " ";
            file << image[i][j].b*255 << " ";
        }
        file << endl;
    }
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
hw1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
hw1.cpp:24: error: template argument for ‘template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator’ uses local type ‘main(int, char**)::RGB’
hw1.cpp:24: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator’
hw1.cpp:24: error: template argument 2 is invalid
hw1.cpp:24: error: template argument 1 is invalid
hw1.cpp:24: error: template argument 2 is invalid
hw1.cpp:24: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
hw1.cpp:25: error: request for member ‘resize’ in ‘image’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
hw1.cpp:27: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
hw1.cpp:32: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
hw1.cpp:33: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
hw1.cpp:34: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
hw1.cpp:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(std::string&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:596: note: candidates are: std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:580: note:                 std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:92: note:                 std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
hw1.cpp:46: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
hw1.cpp:47: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
hw1.cpp:48: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
```

Comment: What are the compiler errors?

Comment: `vector<vector RGB > image;` ? you meant `vector<RGB> image;`?

Comment: probably yes, lol. Most of the time I'm just trying things till it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move `struct RGB` out of main. You can't template on locally declared types.
2. vector of vectors should be declared as:

   ```
   vector< vector<RGB> >
   ```
3. `ofstream` constructor doesn't take `string` object as parameter. Use this instead:

   ```
   ofstream file(filename.c_str());
   ```

Comment: I think thats all of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to declare a `vector` of `vector`s of `RGB`s. You're missing a pair of brackets:

```
vector<vector<RGB> > image;
```

Also, you should be declaring `struct RGB` outside your `main` function.

Comment: It's supposed to be a 2D vector. What did I do wrong?

Comment: From the looks of things, just exactly what I told you above. That aside, it looks like you've about got it right.

Comment: It was the struct in the wrong place giving most of the issues. I'm still getting the line 39 errors

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong with this code.  I'll take you through the first few steps, and hopefully that will give you an idea.

The first compiler error we get is:

```
15: error: ‘atoi’ was not declared in this scope
```

atoi is a library function, so we need to include the right library.  A quick google for "atoi header" tells us this is cstdlib.  Up at the top, we add:

```
#include<cstdlib>
```

The next error we see is:

```
18: error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

Line 18 is:

```
vector<vector RGB > image;
```

The syntax for declaring collections is:

```
collection_type<type_the_collection_is_of> varname;
```

Depending on whether you wanted a vector of pixels or a vector of vectors of pixels, this is one of:

```
vector<RGB> image;
vector< vector<RGB> > image;
```

As a general rule, if the compiler gets confused about a variable declaration, it will get confused about things that happen later when that variable is used.  So lets recompile.

Oops, it's still unhappy about the declaration:
    21: error: template argument for ‘template class std::allocator’ uses local type ‘main(int, char**)::RGB’

"local type".  That's a weird phrase.  Oh.  The struct is defined *inside* the function.  I didn't know that was allowed at all.  Doesn't seem to be working well for us, though, so let's move it outside and compile once more...

This isn't everything, but I hope I've given you a feel for how to debug this sort of thing.